# Почему не выполняется перерасчет размеров файла, автоматически, зная путь к нему?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

***Имееются файлы расположенные в двух местах***

1. @"C:\Users\MSI\Downloads\car_1.png" // размер 642 KB
2. @"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\car_1.png" // размер 27 KB

***Имеется несколько списков (Files, FilesBeforeProcessing, FilesAfterProcessing).*** После вызова методов, показанных в коде, данные из списка Files передаются в другие списки.

1. Со списком FilesBeforeProcessing - полный порядок, он делает полную копию списка Files.
2. Со списком FilesAfterProcessing - не понятности:

   - Если заглянуть в конструктор класса, то видно, что достаточно указать путь к файлу, и остальные свойства сами определят свое содержимое.
   - Когда вызываешь метод GetFilesAfterProcessing(...) и указываваешь только FilePath, то свойство FileSize принимает значение == 0 (ОНО ПОЧЕМУ-ТО НЕ ПЕРЕСЧИТЫВАЕТ РАЗМЕР ФАЙЛА, РАСПОЛОЖЕННЫЙ В ДРУГОМ МЕСТЕ И ИМЕЮЩИЙ ДРУГИЕ РАЗМЕРЫ).
   - Когда вызываешь GetFilesAfterProcessing(...) и указываваешь FilePath И FileSize, то свойство FileSize правильно рассчитывает размер файла.

Если вывести данные в Listbox, то видно, что пути к файлу разнятся, а значит и FileSize должен определяться автоматически (зная путь к файлу).

*!!! Только не пишите о неправильной структуре кода, это только пример*

**Разница, показанная на картинках**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Static Lists**

```
public class ImageCompressorModel {
    public static List<UserFile> FilesBeforeProcessing = new List<UserFile>();
    public static List<UserFile> FilesAfterProcessing = new List<UserFile>();
}
```

**Class "UserFile"**

```
public class UserFile {
    // Поля и Свойства
    public readonly string FileName;
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }
    public long FileSize { get; private set; }

    // Конструкторы класса
    public UserFile() { }
    public UserFile(string path) {
        FilePath = path;
        FileName = new FileInfo(path).Name;
        FileSize = new FileInfo(path).Length;
    }

    // Все данные из основного списка записываются в "FilesBeforeProcessing"
    public List<UserFile> GetFilesBeforeProcessing(List<UserFile> files) {
        return ImageCompressorModel.FilesBeforeProcessing = new List<UserFile>(files);
    }

    // Все данные из основного списка записываются в "FilesAfterProcessing"
    // ! Если указать только FilePath, то FileSize = 0
    // ! Если указать FilePath и FileSize, то FileSize = определяет размер файла
    public List<UserFile> GetFilesAfterProcessing(List<UserFile> files, string outputpath) {
        return ImageCompressorModel.FilesAfterProcessing = files.Select(property => new UserFile {
            FilePath = Path.Combine(outputpath, property.FileName),
            //FileSize = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(outputpath, property.FileName)).Length
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Main form**

```
    List<UserFile> files = new List<UserFile>() {
        new UserFile(@"C:\Users\MSI\Downloads\car_1.png"),
    };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        UserFile compressor = new UserFile();

        List<UserFile> filesBeforeProcessing = compressor.GetFilesBeforeProcessing(files);
        List<UserFile> filesAfterProcessing = compressor.GetFilesAfterProcessing(files, @"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop");

        int length = filesBeforeProcessing.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            listBox1.Items.Add($"Path before: {filesBeforeProcessing[i].FilePath}");
            listBox1.Items.Add($"FileSize before: {filesBeforeProcessing[i].FileSize}");
            listBox1.Items.Add("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            listBox1.Items.Add($"Path after: {filesAfterProcessing[i].FilePath}");
            listBox1.Items.Add($"FileSize after: {filesAfterProcessing[i].FileSize}");
            listBox1.Items.Add("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new UserFile {
            FilePath = Path.Combine(outputpath, property.FileName),
            //FileSize = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(outputpath, property.FileName)).Length
        }
```

При таком вызове конструктора на самом деле вызывается конструктор без параметров (который у вас совсем ничего не делает), после чего одному из полей явно присваивается значение, это эквивалентно примерно такому коду:

```
var userFile = new UserFile();
userFile.FilePath = Path.Combine(outputpath, property.FileName);
```

Поле `userFile.FileSize` при этом остаётся не инициализированным и поэтому оно содержит `0` - дефолтное значение типа `long`.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!